# Installing dependencies of debian/control file

Tags: python, linux, debian

I am in the process of porting a Ruby file used in our build system to Python.  The file looks for `Depends` lines in a `debian/control` file in our repository, checks every dependency, and `apt-get install`s everything that isn't installed.  I am trying to reproduce this functionality.

As part of porting this to Python, I looked at the `deb_pkg_tools` module.  I `pip install`ed it and created a simple script, `install-dep2.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import deb_pkg_tools

controlDict = deb_pkg_tools.control.load_control_file('debian/control')
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:

```
$ build/bin/install-dep2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bin/install-dep2.py", line 4, in <module>
    controlDict = deb_pkg_tools.control.load_control_file('debian/control')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'control'
```

The `debian/control` file exists:

```
$ ls -l debian/control
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 2532 Jul 13 14:28 debian/control
```

How can I process this `debian/control` file?  I don't need to use `deb_pkg_tools` if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is not that Python thinks that `debian/control` does not exist, but rather that it seems like `deb_pkg_tools.control` does not exist.

I would use the `python-debian` package from Debian to parse the control file if I were you. Here is the code that will parse the control file to get the dependencies. It should work even for packages with multiple binary packages.

```
import deb822

for paragraph in deb822.Deb822.iter_paragraphs(open('debian/control')):
    for item in paragraph.items():
        if item[0] == 'Depends':
            print item[1]
```

Each item in the above example is a tuple that pairs the "key" with the "value", so `item[0]` gives us the "key" and `item[1]` gives us the "value".

Obviously the above sample just prints out the dependencies as they are in the control file, so the dependencies aren't in a format that is suitable to directly plug into `apt-get install`. Also, by parsing the control file, I got stuff like `${python:Depends}` in addition to actual package names, so that is something you will have to consider. Here is an example of the output I got from the above example:

```
joseph@crunchbang:~$ python test.py 

 bittornado,
 ${python:Depends},
 python-psutil,
 python-qt4,
 python-qt4reactor,
 python-twisted,
 xdg-utils,
 ${misc:Depends},
 ${shlibs:Depends}
```

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=593525) and the [python-debian source code](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-python-debian/python-debian.git/tree/) to be quite useful resources when answering your question.

Comment: The problem with the python-debian package is that there does not seem to be any documentation (other than the very incomplete docstrings). If anyone knows where it is, please comment here.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look into `mk-build-deps` (from the `devscripts` package) that is a standard script that already does what you want to achieve.

```
$ mk-build-deps -i -s sudo
```